# Nifi: Threads in nifi

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy, apache-nifi

**I want to know how threads work in nifi i mean one processor has one thread or they are in one main thread?** perhaps i want to get one file from processor and then i want to update it

1. how can i prevent getting file data by several processor at a time
   except using keep file =false action?
2. Is  it  possible  to  use  Thread.sleep  inside   Execute  script processor  code?
3. Is  it  possible  to make  same   logic  by  groovy?

I  tried  to  use   java  File  locks but  it  doesn't seem  to  work  good  here  is my  code,

```
     File file = new File("C://Users//user//Desktop//try2//nifi-
      1.3.0//4//conf2.xml");
        String content = "";
        String material = "";
        BufferedReader s;
        BufferedWriter w;
        int m;
        RandomAccessFile ini = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
        FileLock lock = ini.getChannel().lock();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        Document document, doc;
        String date="";
        String data="";
        boolean make = false;
        try {

            String sCurrentLine;
            s = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(ini.getChannel(), "UTF-8"));
            while ((sCurrentLine = s.readLine()) != null) {
                content += sCurrentLine;
            }
            ini.seek(0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to know how threads work in nifi i mean one processor has one thread or they are in one main thread?

Nifi has a configurable pool of threads `( sandwich menu -> controller settings -> general )` and when any processor planned for execution, system takes free thread from the pool, executes processor in this thread, and returns thread to thread pool. So, each processor executes in a separate random thread.

> how can i prevent getting file data by several processor at a time
>    except using keep file =false action?

you need to store a flag `file XXX processed`. how you going to store it - it's your choice. for example you can create an empty file with the same name but with added extension: `conf.xml -> conf.xml.done`. and in code just check if file `conf.xml.done` exists then skip `conf.xml` file processing.

you can store the flag in the database, caching system, etc.

> Is it possible to use Thread.sleep inside Execute script processor code?

possible, but I don't see any sense for this.

> Is it possible to make same logic by groovy?

you can do everything in groovy :)