# How are threads of Processors invoked in Nifi flow?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to learn writing custom Nifi Processor and from the documentation, the processor should be thread-safe. What I wanted to understand is, if, say - I have 100 flow file records connected to my custom processor, would my processor's onTrigger method ( assume that I haven't enabled @TriggerSerially on this method ) be triggered 100 times and in 100 separate threads ( irrespective of concurrently or not ), or is there a possibility that one flow file is used as input to more than one thread of onTrigger method on my processor.

I apologize if I didn't articulate the question correctly, but essentially, is is possible that the number of times my processor's onTrigger method is triggered, is more than the number of flow files that are connected as input to the processor?

Comment: Very similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843397/nifi-threads-in-nifi/46846391

Comment: It's possible that processor triggered even there is no ff in the incoming queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of threads executing a processor is based on the number of concurrent tasks on the scheduling tab, which defaults to 1. If you increase this to 2, then 2 threads are concurrently executing the onTrigger method. A single flow file will only be processed by one of these threads.

The @TriggerSerially annotation prevents you from being able to increase the conccurent tasks, so it forces there to never be concurrent execution. A common use case for this would be a source processor that is pulling data from somewhere, typically you wouldn't to concurrently be pulling the same data twice.