# Bit clarification about concurrent tasks property in nifi processors

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I was using concurrent tasks set to 50 for PutDataBaseRecord and For Postgresql DBCPPoolingConnection service I was using maximum connections to unlimited but, PutDataBaseRecord processor was considering maximum 10 flow files for processing. (I was using only one Node)

**Observation:-**
I can see only 10 threads are being using by the processes in over all flow. Suppose, The upstream processor for PutDataBaseRecord was ExecuteSql .., so while ExecuteSql using 3 threads PutDataBaseRecord was using 7 threads and When ExecuteSqk using 2 threads PutDataBaseRecord was using 8 threads and so on.

Can someone make me understand where i'm going wrong. What actually is happening and Why is it like that?

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843397/nifi-threads-in-nifi/46846391#46846391

Comment: I'm sorry, still not able to understand. Can you please help me understanding

Comment: there is a total number of threads/workers all over nifi node. defined here: `sandwich menu -> controller settings -> general`. so, if you have total=10 and some processor is using 3 - then 7 threads are available to other processors. just go to menu and change total treads value for example to 100 - so 50 will be available for put-db-record and other 50 to rest of processors.